# Assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: c

I'm getting this warning:

```
warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

The issue is, that `symbolP` is not `const`. I don't want to create `const char *symbolP` every time in a loop.
How can I solve it in a better way.
Here the snippet:

```
int getList(OCI_Connection* cn)
{
  OCI_Statement* st;
  OCI_Resultset* rs;
  char *symbolP;

  char *query ="SELECT ..";

  st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);
  OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, query);
  rs = OCI_GetResultset(st);
  while (OCI_FetchNext(rs))
  {
      //here comes the warning:
      symbolP = OCI_GetString(rs,1);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You are likely getting this error on the line: `symbolP = OCI_GetString(rs,1);`.  Guess which function definition you did not include in your question??

Comment: Since you never use symbolP, why even have the assignment?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is the mentioned line. I have edited the question.

Comment: I use it, but is cutted off.

Comment: char const *c does not mean the pointer is constant, it means the character it points to is constant. The compiler wouldn't warn for not having a char * const, because that isn't part of the return type.  You can also just shut the compiler up with a (char *) cast.

Comment: Why aren't people posting their answers as an *answer*, I really cannot understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `const char *symbolP`, and it is no less efficient than using `char *symbolP`. Also, the *pointer* remains assignable:

- `const char *` = a non-constant pointer to a constant `char`
- `char * const` = a constant pointer to a non-constant `char`
- `const char * const` = a constant pointer to a constant `char`

Now, if the code that you didn't show actually modifies the string being pointed to, then it is an error and you need to make a modifiable copy first. This is also a good reason to use the proper `const char *` pointer: you will get the correct error.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to fix it would actually be to declare a const in your loop if it is what returns `OCI_GetString`.

However it depends on what you want to do with this data. If you just want to display it you can directly use `OCI_GetString` in a `printf`.

An other solution: if you know a priori the size of the strings returned by `OCI_GetString` maybe you can try to use it in a `memcpy` or `strcpy` using the same buffer in every loop.

Comment: you don't have to know anything about the returned size of this string before calling OCI_GetString. You can get it after OCI_GetString and then copy the string.

Comment: Actually my idea was to reserve a static buffer prior to the loop: you need at least to know the maximal size that will be used to reserve enough space for it.